# Rails migration to add a column of type array of objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration

I would like to add a column of type `Array of Objects`.

```
 "users_to_employer":[
     {
       key1 : value,
       key2 : value,
     },
     {
       key1: value,
       key2: value,
     }
  ]
```

I am stuck in migration.

`add_column :table_name, :column_name, ......`

What to write in place of ......

Comment: which data base you are using? postgres, mysql or mongodb?

Comment: @G.B using postgres database

Comment: @ashvin has answered which seems legit. You can also have a look on `hstore` for `postgres` which stores hashes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a column with datatype text

```
add_column :table_name, :column_name, :text, default: "" #Field type should be text to store array of hashes
```

In your model serialize it to convert it into array

```
class TableName < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :column_name, Array
end
```

Hope this will help you

Answer (score 2):

If you are on PostgreSQL, you may try different solutions, such as:

1. Array column type

```
    
    create_table :table_name do |t|
      ...
      t.string 'array_column_name', array: true
      ...
    end

    add_index :table_name, :array_column_name, using: 'gin'


    # Usage
    YourModel.create(array_column_name: ["value1", "value2"])
```

2. Or you can try to store your data as JSON

```
    create_table :table_name do |t|
      t.json 'json_column_name'
    end

    # Usage
    YoutModel.create(json_column_name: { key1: "val1", key2: ["val21", "val22"]})
```

and parse your json more flexible, to array and other structures.

More information you can see at [official Rails documentation](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_postgresql.html)

Answer (score 2):

```
add_column :table_name, :column_name, :string, array: true
```